# How to access parent's JSON object from iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a html code like below.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  user_data = {
  name: 'xyz',
  age: 123
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
.... some code ---
<iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
var userName = user_data.name;
});
</head>
<body>
<!--- some other code -->
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I am trying to access user_data object which is in index.html from test.html (iframe file).

Can somebody help me to get the value in iframe.

Comment: You can try passing object as url parameters to Iframe using jQuery.param function and constructing Iframe dynamically with Javascript

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move your script from head to body.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Parent</h1>
    <iframe src="./test.html"></iframe>
    <script>
     user_data = {
        name: "xyz",
        age: 123
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then access parent data with [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)

```
<body>
    <h1>Test Html</h1>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
        const { parent = {} } = window;
        const { user_data = {} } = parent;
        const { name, age} = user_data;
        const $app = document.getElementById('app')
        $app.innerText = `name: ${name}, age: ${age}`
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is a [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/access-iframe-parent-data-mou16)

Comment: Erro "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin \"null\" from accessing a cross-origin frame" comes.. Pls check the result.

Comment: Try Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/access-iframe-parent-data-mou16   – removed confusing button from answer.